# Printer issue with Konica Minolta C253 - print outs look different

Tags: printer, colors, graphics, network-printer

We're having an issue in our office with a printer, and it's got me a little stumped.

Two different users, when printing the same document with the same graphics to the same printer, see a different result in the color of the print out.

So far, the biggest difference that I can see are that the two machines have different OSes (XP vs Windows 7), and thus presumably different drivers.

However, the XP machine is the one that appears to be printing correctly.

Can anyone think of a good place to start with this?

Answer (score 0):

After working there for some years, I found that the drivers for Vista and 7 sorta suck... Having said that, try a generic driver on the Windows 7 computer first and let us know if the colors match up